# C++ executable crash

Tags: executable

I tried to generate an executable code for my program but it always crashes. It was okay in release / debug mode. This is the only change I have done based on the website http://xoax.net/cpp/crs/visualcpp/lessons/CreateExe/

[image]

Comment: If it hurts then stop hitting it. Did it work the first time around?

Comment: Hello yes it worked in both debug and release mode but the exe file generated crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When choosing **release** configuration the run time library should be **Multi-Threaded**.
In **debug** configuration you should choose **Multi-Threaded Debug**.

Comment: Wow thanks ! I followed the website stated earlier and it worked for a simpler project.